# Get "raw" value from invalid input field

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field in a form with some validations. It works like a charm.

It basically looks like this:

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  type="number"
  ng-model="zipcode"
  ng-minlength="5"
  ng-maxlength="5"
  id="zipcode"
  name="zipcode"
  required
>
```

A working plunkr is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/H0h59kG75T5MGE9cAhSo?p=preview

But now I also want to react to every input change - whether valid or not. So for example if the input field contains "123" it is not valid and the value is not transferred to my model - thats fine. But I still want to get the value to do some intermediate requests to a webservice.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think you are going to have to handle min and max in the controller to get this to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what i came up with for your scenario.

Basically you can write a directive which requires `ngModel` (ngModelController). The ngModelController has a array of parsers which it call to parse the view value in a pipeline manner. If validation fail these parsers do not update the model. If you inject a custom parser at the start of this parsers array, you can get the each view change value and do anything you want with it.

See my plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/ruB42xHWj7dBxe885OGy?p=preview  (See console)

The basic code would be

```
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.splice(0,0,(function (viewValue) {
              console.log("The view value is:"+viewValue)
                return viewValue;           
            }));
```

Also see [ngModelController documenation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController)

Comment: Thank you very much especially for the extremely fast answere. Also: works like a charm ;)

Comment: Thanks again. IMO your answere was well worth a blog post, so here it is: http://wasis.nu/mit/blog?postId=527aafe9975ab23791ba6da8

Comment: Great! i too was thinking the same. I looked at your post and it you improve this implementation.

Answer (score 13):

First call the form element in your controller, then use the `$viewValue` attribute :

**View :**

```
<form name="form">
<input
  ...
  ng-model="zipcode"
  ng-change="getRawValue(form)"
  name="zipcode"
  required
>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getRawValue = function(form) {
  var rawValue = form.zipcode.$viewValue;
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer IMO.  It's much simpler and doesn't need a directive.

Comment: Jay, thanks! Just need "form.zipcode.$viewValue" .. easy solution!

Comment: It's my understanding that $viewValue is distinct from the value that is ran through parsers, but not yet considered valid and committed to the model. So, while they're most often the same value, they're not always.

Answer (score 13):

Angular 1.3 introduced a real answer for this: `allowInvalid` in [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Example:

```html
<input 
    type="text"
    name="userName"
    ng-model="user.name"
    ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
>
```

Comment: This, IMO, is the cleanest way to work with the invalid value.  This does not require a directive, or even a special function to work with it.  Just drop this in, and it works.

Comment: I been looking for this answer all over the place.  I'm just shocked at how hard it was to find.  Thank you!