# Access HTML form input value if ng-model is invalid

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel

Suppose I have form with one input and validation rules like min-length, max-length, etc. I want to show hint to user how much symbols he should append to (or remove from) current input value to pass validation rules. But ng-model that corresponds to this input is empty because input is invalid. How can I access current input value?

Comment: Check here for a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817602/get-raw-value-from-invalid-input-field

Comment: I'm looking for more elegant solution. Eg. Something like myForm.myInput.value?

Comment: The link that @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE provided _is_ the elegant solution.  If you look at the comments there is a [blog](http://wasis.nu/mit/blog?postId=527aafe9975ab23791ba6da8) which evens shows you how to create a re-usable directive that is even easier to use.